# Android - error boolean Intent

Tags: java, android

can you tell me when I write this line of code:

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences ("PREFERENCE" MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean ("isShowcaseView", true);

if (isFirstRun)
{
    startActivity (new Intent (DownloadIVase.this,ActivityShowcaseInfo.class));
    getSharedPreferences ("PREFERENCE" MODE_PRIVATE) .edit ().putBoolean ("isShowcaseView", false) .commit ();
}
```

the `startActivity()` works,

But when I change the line

`startActivity (new Intent (DownloadIVase.this, ActivityShowcaseInfo.class));`

To

```
startActivity (new Intent (DownloadIVase.this, ActivityShowcaseInfo.class), ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

it crash

Comment: `Boolean = isFirstRun` use like this ..........`Boolean isFirstRun=`

Comment: sorry I misspelled ...
Here I have corrected

Comment: you are passing wrong params according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity, android.view.View, java.lang.String) there are 3 parameters for calling `activityOptions`

Comment: Post your logcat for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code while you are using `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MyActivity.this, ivUserPic, "transitionName");
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

In `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` last argument is `sharedElementName`.

That means you’ll need to configure which view in your child activity will be the view getting animated to during the Transition. In order to specify this, you’ll need to give it a name.

```
android:transitionName="transitionName"
```

Here I added it in `ImageView`. You can also set it by programmatically like:

```
ivUserPic.setTransitionName("transitionName");
```